# how to read HTTP Header's Content-Disposition: form-data

Tags: http, vbscript, header

I am sending some data with HTTP header's `Content-Disposition: form-data`
something like this:

```
--------------010201080703010401070605
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="age"

25
--------------010201080703010401070605
```

How to I read this data with VBScript?
I tried:

```
var_age = Request("age") 'not work
var_age = Request.age    'not work
```

Comment: Assuming this question is actually about [tag:asp-classic] rather than plain (i.e. client-side) VBScript, try [`Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_CONTENT_DISPOSITION")`](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_servervariables.asp).

Comment: Thanks but how do I exactly use it? Like Request.ServerVariables("age") ?

Comment: I don't use ASP, but I suspect you'll have to parse the header string.

Comment: thanks I will try to find out

Comment: I find out why it doesn't work. It just that the format of the multipart-form-data is incorrect..so request("age") would work fine.